# How can I know why I get "Permission denied" page?

Tags: django, admin

On some action in my admin I get a "Permission denied" page, and in the debug log I get

```
[26/Jun/2012 08:23:59] "POST /admin/securite_v2/magasin/ HTTP/1.0" 403 26
```

How can I see what's going on exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely as it said, permissions related.

Try do a CHMOD 777 on that DIR and its contents, and see if the error persists. Be sure not to leave it as 777 though - this would create a considerable security risk.

Comment: Is there any way to know which file Django cannot access?

Comment: If you check your log, you should see what it's trying to access. If CHMOD fails you, it's likely giving a csrf error, which manifests itself as a 403. I'd recommend reading over https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it if that's the case.